# What exactly is happening when I set an object's property using an accessor method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties, accessor

Say I have an object called MyClass, which has a property defined as `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *foo;` and I synthesize that property.

Then in another class, say the application delegate I define a string (but it could be anything) `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi"];` and call on an instance of MyClass: `[myClass setFoo:myString];`

What actually happens? Does the reference to the space that was allocated for `myString` get set? Or does it get what is in the allocated memory for `myString` and set it to the allocated memory for `foo`, since I called `retain` on `foo`?

And I have to release `myString` in the application delegate. And I have to release `foo` in MyClass, since it was retained, but do I have to release it again since another alloc'd variable was assigned to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends how the property is declared. Because yours is `(retain)`, it will keep the same object pointer, and also automatically send `-retain` so it can ensure access to the memory whether or not the caller holds a reference. If you used `(copy)`, it would send `-copy` which would make a new object that's a copy of the old one (provided the object conforms to `NSCopying).

This all happens in the accessories implementation, which is commonly generated for you when you use `@synthesize`. If you implement your own, be sure to use the correct behavior!

Comment: so then does that mean that if I change either myString or foo, it will change the other one since they are actually just references to the same variable.

Comment: Kind of — remember that you can't change an `NSString`, only a `NSMutableString`. And `NSString` properties are usually `(copy)` anyway.

Comment: yeah. this isnt a real example i am just taking about objects in general, not strings. so say it was a nsmutablestring and i did changed one, would it change the other?

Comment: Yes, if it is not `(copy)`. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

`@synthesize` basically creates two methods for you. In your case those two methods would be similar to this:

```
-(NSString*) foo;
{
    return foo; //synthesized ivar
}

-(void) setFoo:(NSString*)newValue;
{
    if(foo != newValue){
        [foo release];
        foo = [newValue retain];
    }
}
```

However, `@synthesize` won't release the value in `dealloc`, so you have to do that manually.

Objects in Objective-C are treated as pointers, so when you say `NSString* a = b;` you're not copying the object itself, you're just making another pointer to the object. Synthesized properties are no exception to this.

Comment: This is only correct for `(nonatomic)` properties, I believe :)

Comment: Yes. It would be slightly different if the property in the question was atomic.

Comment: Which I believe Tom did include a caveat at the beginning of his answer. The implementation of the synthesize methods is correct for the keywords the OP is using.

Comment: Actually, `@synthesize foo;` creates code like: `return [[foo retain] autorelease];`. If the property is atomic, it will also put locks around the code in `setFoo:`.

Comment: FWIW, string properties are usually declared as `(copy)`, and then a copy *is* made.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, it actually doesn't autorelease the ivar from the synthesized accessor method.

Comment: From the getter? Are you sure?

Comment: I remembered reading something about it a while ago, so I tested it 5 minutes ago and autorelease wasn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the object `myString` points to gets its retain count incremented by one when you do `[myClass setFoo:myString];`

Initially, when you alloc a string and store the reference in `myString`, the retain count is 1. Storing it in a property with retain like you have, gets its retain count incremented to 2.

No you don't have to release it again. Max retain count is 2. Hence 2 releases.